# Local test on java application that has no context root

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, root, contextpath

Here's a sample link from my jsp:

```
<a href="/admin/articleEdit">New Article</a>
```

My application will be deployed with no context root so such links will work in production. But locally, this fails because the link does not contain the context root. I've tried to start links with "./" but that does not always solve related issues.

Is there a way to locally test java application using Eclipse and Eclipse-embedded Tomcat server with no context root? Eclipse does not let me remove context root from the project. I've tried setting context root to "/" but that does not help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Double click on your Tomcat instance in the *Servers* list to edit it.
2. Select the *Modules* tab on the bottom.
3. Highlight your webapp and click the *Edit* button.
4. Keep *document base* as is, set *path* to blank.
5. Confirm with *OK*.
6. Make sure the webapp is published and (re)start the server.

Comment: Hm, I've tried that before and it wasn't working. Now, it does. Thanks.

Comment: This is the wrong approach.  Fix the href instead, to include the context path (as below) and then your app can be deployed with whichever path you need.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the context root, fix your jsp hrefs. See the answers to this question: [Any clever ways of handling the context in a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/125359/116509)