# Images not found in Spring - can not find resources folder

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, resources, directory

I have the following folder structure. I added mvc annotation and resources path but when I try call the resources in `home.jsp` like `<img src= "/resources/images/spitter_avatar.png" />`, it can't find anything.

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**Here is my code in my servlet-config.xml file for resources:**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<img src= "resources/images/spitter_avatar.png" />
```

try above remove "/"  before resources

Comment: thank you it works. But what should I change to use it like `/resources` in jsp file.

Comment: you have to add project name before /resources in your case its Spring3MVC so ie `src="/Spring3MVC/resources/images/spitter_avatar.png"`

Comment: something like that `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/Spring3MVC/resources/" />` does not work. I need to use it `<img src= "/resources/images/spitter_avatar.png" />` like that in jsp file

Comment: @SerhatC See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125359/any-clever-ways-of-handling-the-context-in-a-web-app) for some solutions to this problem.

Comment: Ok thanks :) I'll look into it a little bit more later but it is a good post.

Comment: I forgot to accept this answer before, thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

if you wanted to start with / , then use JSTL C tag

```
<img src= "<c:url value="/resources/images/spitter_avatar.png"></c:url>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `resources` folder must be located inside the **WebContent folder**.
2. Place `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` **before your items url** on the jsp page. Example:

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/springlogo.svg
```